# Loading JSON Data via NG click (JS)

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am having a problem loading a set of JSON data with NG CLICK.  Without the clickButton function the data loads fine.  Is my JSON data structured properly?  Here is my fiddle.  Click [here] (http://jsfiddle.net/al321/08rjqv4k/3/ "mouse over")

```
    $scope.items = [
    {
    "Name":"Sam",

    "Address":"Street",

    "Phone":"111",

    "status":"Available"

    }, 

    {
    "Name":"Tom",

    "Address":"Road",

    "Phone":"222",

    "status":"Busy"

    },]

   --js
   var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

    app.controller('myController', 
   ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {

   $scope.clickButton = function() {
   $http.get('data.json').success(function(data) {
    $scope.items = data.items;
  });
  }

   }]);
```

Answer (score 1):

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/H4PhUsO8FyN78ZaQUaHT?p=preview)

JS

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myController', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
  $scope.clickButton = function() {
    $http.get('data.json').success(function(data) {
        $scope.items = data;
      });
  }

}]);
```

Markup

```
  <body ng-controller="myController">
     <div ng-app="myApp">
        <div ng-controller="myController">
          <button ng-click='clickButton()'>Load Data</button>
          <ul ng-repeat="item in items">
            <li ng-repeat="(key, val) in item">{{key}}: {{val}}
            </li>
        </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
  </body>
```

JSON

```
[
  {
        "Name":"Sam",

        "Address":"Street",

        "Phone":"111",

        "status":"Available"

    }, 

    {
        "Name":"Tom",

        "Address":"Road",

        "Phone":"222",

        "status":"Busy"

    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are trying to accomplish?

Just replace the contents of the clickButton() function with your ajax calls.

You forgot to put the `()` on `ng-click="clickButton()`.  You need to actually call the function.

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/kn5Q0fHOABl5aUjlkv8L?p=preview)

To add the search functionality you mentioned in the comment, just add a filter to the first `ng-repeat`:

```
ng-repeat="item in items| filter: {Name: search}"
```

[Plunker with search](http://plnkr.co/edit/kn5Q0fHOABl5aUjlkv8L?p=preview)

Comment: Yes it is.  Thanks.  I will now attempt to use ng model(search) and tie that to the data.  For example:  Type Sam in a form, click search and it finds all Sam Json data.